# WinAPI/GDI: How to use GetDIBits() to get color table synthesized for a bitmap?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I find it difficult to understand the excerpt below from MSDN site on `GetDIBits()` function:

> If *lpvBits* is **NULL** and the bit count member of **BITMAPINFO** is
>   initialized to zero, **GetDIBits** fills in a **BITMAPINFOHEADER**
>   structure or **BITMAPCOREHEADER** without the color table. This
>   technique can be used to query bitmap attributes.

Question-1: What is meant by "the bit count member of BITMAPINFO"? Does it mean `some_bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount`?

Question-2: What is meant by "GetDIBits fills in a BITMAPINFOHEADER structure or BITMAPCOREHEADER without the color table"? What color table *is there* to fill in those structures? None of them seems to have a member related to the color table. Is this about the array `some_bmi.bmiColors`?

Question-3: Is there a way to use `GetDIBits()` to get the color table(i.e. the array mapping indexes to colors) for a bitmap?

---

EDIT:

From the comments so far, it looks like breaking the question down into smaller parts was not effective. I will try it another way.

This is what I understand from the part I quoted from MSDN at the beginning:

Assuming the function call is `GetDIBits(hdc, hbmp, uStartScan, cScanLines, lpvBits, lpbi, uUsage)`; if *lpvBits* is NULL and `lpvBits->bmiHeader.biBitCount` is initialized to zero, GetDIBits() fills in `lpbi->bmiHeader` only and `lpbi->bmiColors` is not modified.

Is this the correct way to understand it? And if so, is there a way to get GetDIBits() to fill in `lpbi->bmiColors`, such as initializing `lpvBits->bmiHeader.biBitCount` to bit-depth of the bitmap?

---

I tried testing Question-1's assumption as follows but GetDIBits() fails in that case:

```
void test(HWND hWnd) {
    // get a memory DC
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    HDC hdcmem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); // has 1x1 mono bitmap selected 
                                          // into it initially by default
    // select a 16x16 mono bmp into it
    const int bmp_h = 16, bmp_w = 16;
    const int bits_per_px = 1;
    HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcmem, bmp_h, bmp_w); // 16x16 mono bitmap
    HGDIOBJ hOldBmp = SelectObject(hdcmem, hbmp);

    // initialize BITMAPINFO ptr
    // (make sure to allocate a buffer large enough for 2 RGBQUADs 
    // in case color table is retured by GetDIBits() call)
    const int bmi_buf_sz =
        sizeof(BITMAPINFO) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * (1 << bits_per_px); // 2 + 1(extra) RGBQUADs allocated for pbmi->bimColors
    BYTE* p_bmi_buf = new BYTE[bmi_buf_sz];
    BITMAPINFO* pbmi = reinterpret_cast<BITMAPINFO*>(p_bmi_buf);
    ZeroMemory(pbmi, bmi_buf_sz);

    // populate BITMAPINFO
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 1; // set to 1 just to see if GetDIBits()
                                    // fills in pbmi->bmiColors too
                                   // (when set to 0, only pbmi->bmiHeader is filled)
    if(!GetDIBits(hdcmem, hbmp,
                  0, (UINT)bmp_h,
                  NULL, pbmi, DIB_PAL_COLORS)) {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"GetDIBits() failed!", NULL, MB_OK);
    }

    // clean-up
    delete[] p_bmi_buf;
    SelectObject(hdcmem, hOldBmp); // push hbmp out
    DeleteObject(hbmp);
    DeleteDC(hdcmem);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
}
```

Comment: All of this is explained in exhaustive detail in the MSDN. See [Bitmaps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183377.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable : I have already read whole "Bitmaps" section and, almost all of the general MSDN documentation about GDI, but I still cannot make sense of the quoted part in OP. I am quite new to GDI, and it is always possible I might have missed something. I would greatly appreciate it if you could point me to a more specific part that relates to my questions.

Comment: The color tables are explained in great detail, for example. 1-, 2-, 4-, and 8-bpp bitmaps have color tables, immediately following the `BITMAPINFO` structure. 16- and higher bpp bitmaps do not have color tables. That answers question 2. The others are also answered in the link. Maybe you just need to read it again.

Comment: @IInspectable : I think I have well enough grip those parts. I fear it could be that maybe my OP is not clear enough. My questions are not related to what quoted parts mean in general. It is just that they don't make sense to me in those contexts. For example, I know what a "color table" is, or where it is when it exists in a bitmap. I just don't understand what "filling in a `BITMAPINFOHEADER` structure without the color table" means. `BITMAPINFOHEADER` does not contain the color table. It is stored in `bmiColors` array member of `BITMAPINFO`.

Comment: You *are* passing a `BITMAPINFO` structure to `GetDIBits`.

Comment: @IInspectable : Just to be clear: Are you saying my assumption in Question-2 is correct? That is, what `GetDIBits()` fills with color table(or does not fill depending on some condition I don't understand as stated in Q1), is actually `bmiColors` member of `BITMAPINFO` and *not* any member in `BITMAPINFOHEADER`?(which is what I would expect from what I understand)

Comment: `GetDibBits` will get bits, that's the stuff which comes after palette (if there is any) or it will fill `BITMAPINFO` structure. It has nothing to do with palette. Even if your function works, it will end up doing nothing. You should ask one question with a specific goal.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani : Here is what confuses the hell out of me about the part I quoted from the documentation: If, as you suggest, `GetDIBits()` has *nothing* to do with the "palette"(and assuming by "palette" you mean the "color table"), why then does the quote mention the function not filling `BITMAPINFOHEADER` with "color table"? As far as I can see, `BITMAPINFOHEADER` has no members related to "color table", anyway. Why mention it, then? It seems to imply that if `lpvBits` arg is NULL, but "bit count"(whatever that means) is non-zero, it would somehow fill the color table.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani : Your comment relates mostly to my Q2 and Q3. What are your thoughts on my Q1?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani : By the way, I edited the question as per your suggestion.

Comment: Looking at the code, you seem to have ignored the following from the [GetDIBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879.aspx) documentation: *"The bitmap identified by the* hbmp *parameter must not be selected into a device context when the application calls this function."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the color table is with `GetDibColorTable`:

```
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
HBITMAP oldbmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
int ncolors = 1 << bm.bmBitsPixel;
std::vector<RGBQUAD> rgb(ncolors);
if(ncolors == GetDIBColorTable(memdc, 0, ncolors, &rgb[0]))
{
    //success!
}
SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
DeleteDC(memdc);
```

Back to your question: `GetDIBits` expects `pbmi` to contain all zeros (except for `bmiHeader.biSize` member). So `pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount` should be zero.

```
//pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 1; <<= comment out this line
```

This should work; however, as it is stated in documentation, this will only fill the info header, not the color table. To get the color table you have to make another call to `GetDIBits` with enough allocation for the dib bits.

Moreover `DIB_PAL_COLORS` will return palette index array (I am not sure what you can do with that). You may want to use `DIB_RGB_COLORS` flag which will return actual colors when a color table is present.

Try this with a bitmap loaded from file:

```
HBITMAP hbitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(0, L"8bit.bmp",
    IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE);

BITMAP bm;
GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);

//don't continue for hi color bitmaps
if(bm.bmBitsPixel > 8) return;

int ncolors = 1 << bm.bmBitsPixel;
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
int bmpinfo_size = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * ncolors;
std::vector<BYTE> buf(bmpinfo_size);
BITMAPINFO* bmpinfo = (BITMAPINFO*)buf.data();
bmpinfo->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
if(!GetDIBits(memdc, hbitmap, 0, bm.bmHeight, NULL, bmpinfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    //...
}

int dibsize = ((bm.bmWidth * bm.bmBitsPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * bm.bmHeight;
std::vector<BYTE> dib(dibsize);
if(!GetDIBits(memdc, hbitmap, 0, (UINT)bm.bmHeight, &dib[0], bmpinfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    //...
}
```

Now `bmpinfo->bmiColors` should contain the same values as `rgb` array shown earlier.

---

Possible confusion between `BITMAPINFO` and `BITMAPINFOHEADER`:

The above structures are declared as follows:

```
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFO {
    BITMAPINFOHEADER    bmiHeader;
    RGBQUAD             bmiColors[1];
} BITMAPINFO, FAR *LPBITMAPINFO, *PBITMAPINFO;

typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER{
        DWORD      biSize;
        LONG       biWidth;
        LONG       biHeight;
        WORD       biPlanes;
        WORD       biBitCount;
        DWORD      biCompression;
        DWORD      biSizeImage;
        LONG       biXPelsPerMeter;
        LONG       biYPelsPerMeter;
        DWORD      biClrUsed;
        DWORD      biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER, FAR *LPBITMAPINFOHEADER, *PBITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

So `BITMAPINFO` does not have `biBitCount` member. But it does have `bmiHeader.biBitCount` member.

When you declare a `BITMAPINFOHEADER` variable, you have to set `biSize` member (that's Windows' idea of version control). When you declare a `BITMAPINFO` variable, you have to make sure it's `BITMAPINFOHEADER` is taken care of.

Note that most of the time you don't have to worry about palette. For example `LoadImage` will return a compatible bitmap (if you don't specify `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION`) and you can use that right away.

Comment: All clear finally, thank you. Now I see the critical point in all my misunderstandings was that I thought calling `GetDIBits()` with a fully initialized `bmiHeader` member of `BITMAPINFO` struct filled `lpvBits` only, whereas in fact it fills `bmiColors` member as well. I just wish it were clear in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, it took me an hour to figure out the documentation too.

Comment: Using `GetDIBits` with `lpvBits` set to `NULL` will fill `BITMAPINFO`. But I think it's better to fill `BITMAPINFO` manually. Usually you can get all the necessary `BITMAPINFO` values from `BITMAP` and `GetObject` ...

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer covers the details, this is more of a direct answer to the questions in the OP.

Assuming the function call is `GetDIBits(hdc, hbmp, uStartScan, cScanLines, lpvBits, lpbi, uUsage)`;

*Question-1:*

That is correct. "The bit count member of BITMAPINFO" refers to `lpbi->bmiHeader.biBitCount`.

*Question-2:*

When `GetDIBits()` is called to get DIB bits(i.e. with a non-null `lpvBits` and an appropriately initialized `lpbi->bmiHeader`), `lpbi->bmiColors` also gets filled by the function with the color table(if bit depth is less then 24 bpp). 
Unfortunately, this is not clear in the documentation of the function. With that in mind, what the quoted part means is that, when `lpvBits` is NULL and `lpbi->bmiHeader.biBitCount` is zero, the function fills `lpbi->bmiHeader` **only**, and does **not** modify `lpbi->bimColor`(as opposed to when caling the function to get DIB bits).

*Question-3:*

You can get the function to return color table(for bitmaps with 8-bbp or less) in `lpbi->bmiColors` by calling it with a non-null `lpvBits` and an appropriately initialized `lpbi->bmiHeader`. IOW, when you call the function to get DIB bits as usual, it fills `lpbi->bmiColors` as well.

*Question in EDIT section:*

> If *lpvBits* is NULL and `lpvBits->bmiHeader.biBitCount` is initialized to
>   zero, GetDIBits() fills in `lpbi->bmiHeader` only and `lpbi->bmiColors` is
>   not modified.
>
> Is this the correct way to understand it?

Yes, that is correct.

> And if so, is there a way to get GetDIBits() to fill in
>   `lpbi->bmiColors`, such as initializing `lpvBits->bmiHeader.biBitCount` to
>   bit-depth of the bitmap?

Yes, there is a way to get the function to return the color table, but as explained in answer to Q2, initializing `lpvBits->bmiHeader.biBitCount` to bit-depth of the bitmap alone is not enough. All members of `lpvBits->bmiHeader` must be appropriately initialized and `lpvBits` must be non-null. This is basically the same as calling the function to get the DIB bits.